# How to force ExecutorService to run immediately?

Tags: java, threadpool, java-threads

I have an ExecutorService and I want to run messageConsumer thread immediately. When I run below code it logs "submit completed" but after nearly 4-5 minutes messageConsumer thread starting.

I want to force this thread to run immediately.

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> threadPoolQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
ThreadPoolExecutor executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(50, 50, 30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, threadPoolQueue, new CustomThreadFactory("consumers"));
executorService.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);

MessageConsumer messageConsumer = new MessageConsumer(chargingService, messageSender);
executorService.submit(messageConsumer);
logger.debug("submit completed.");
```

Here is MessageConsumer;

```
public class MessageConsumer implements Runnable {
   public void run() {
      logger.debug("MessageConsumer starting...");
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** I am using java 7 by the way.

```
public class CustomThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

 private static final AtomicInteger poolNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
 private final ThreadGroup group;
 private final AtomicInteger threadNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
 private final String namePrefix;

 public CustomThreadFactory(String groupName) {
    SecurityManager s = System.getSecurityManager();
    group = (s != null) ? s.getThreadGroup()
            : Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
    namePrefix = groupName + "-thread";
 }

 @Override
 public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
    Thread t = new Thread(group, r, namePrefix + "-" + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(), 0);
    if (t.isDaemon()) {
        t.setDaemon(false);
    }
    if (t.getPriority() != Thread.NORM_PRIORITY) {
        t.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
    }
    return t;
 }
}
```

Comment: @NicolasFilotto yes it must be ThreadPoolExecutor my fault I have updated my code.

Comment: You can force a poolcorethread to be started with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#prestartCoreThread-- ... have you tried that?

Comment: @Fildor I am using java 7 and ThreadPoolExecutor doesn't have a method like preStartCoreThread.

Comment: That function was there in Java 7 also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#prestartCoreThread()

Comment: Does MessageConsumer's run actually have an infinite loop? It should have if it is supposed to run infinitely. (Infinite in the sense of "must explicitly be shut down")

Comment: @Fildor I have just found out preStartCoreThread method but I have some other threads in ThreadPool. Is there a way to run only messageConsumer thread?

Comment: What does your CustomThreadFactory do? Maybe something inside that is holding the MessageConsumer execution.

Comment: @RaphaelMoita I have added CustomThreadFactory.

Comment: Maybe you are better off simply starting a good old-fashioned Thread?